# How can we pass values to dialog widget?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

```
function click1(a)
{
var srcdivid =$(a).closest('div').attr('id');

$("#pagetemplate").dialog("open"); return false;
}
```

Here I get the value srcdivid and i hav to pass this value to above dialogue.how its possible?

My dialogue widget code is following

```
<?php 
$this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array(
    'id'=>'pagetemplate',
        'options'=>array(
        'title'=>'Page Template',
        'autoOpen'=>false,
        'modal'=>true,
        'width'=>1000,
        'height'=>300       
    ),
));?>
<input type="hidden" name="padeidvalue" id="padeidvalue">
<?php if(count($templatemodel) > 0){
    for($i=0;$i<count($templatemodel);$i++){
echo "<div class='temp-thumb'><a class='".$templatemodel[$i]['template_image_name']."' onclick='addtemplate(".$templatemodel[$i]['page_template_id'].");' href='#'></a></div>";
    }

}else{
    echo "<p>Opps!.  No Templates Found></p>";
}?>

<?php $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');?>
```

Here I call the addtemplate function. Its definition as follows

```
function addtemplate(params){

var srcdivid ="";
alert(srcdivid);
alert(params);
$.ajax({
    url:baseURL+"/index.php/MyAlbums/AddTemplatesToDiv",
    type:'POST',
    data:{"templateid":params,"divid":"srcdivid" },
    success:function(data){
        $("#"+srcdivid).html(data.template);
        $("#pagetemplate").dialog("close");
        $(".imgborderclass").removeClass("imgborderclass");
        addClass();
        addComm();
    },      
});   
}
```

I have to get srcdivid in this addtemplate function which i pass from click function. help me please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method of jQuery.

```
function click1(a) {
    var srcdivid =$(a).closest('div').attr('id');
    $("#pagetemplate").data('srcdivid', srcdivid);
    $("#pagetemplate").dialog("open"); return false;
}

function addtemplate(params) {
    var srcdivid = $("#pagetemplate").data('srcdivid');
    alert(srcdivid);
    ...
}
```